# Can I enable my App for AirPlay?

Tags: objective-c, ios, airplay

If I create my own custom Application for iOS (XCode/Objective-C), can I make it support AirPlay and beam scren content of my choice to an Apple TV?

What APIs/Function Calls am I looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea behind the AirPlay support is to play the video content from your app.

If you're a registered iOS Developer, you will be able to find the documentation and examples at the iOS 4 beta section after you login. As this is still a beta release for 4.3 version, documentation is under confidential agreement.

It's pretty much easy and straightforward. You should start looking by `MPMoviePlayerController`.