# Send UITableview to airplay from iPod touch 4th gen (IOS 5.0)

Tags: objective-c, ios, airplay

I would like to ask whether is feasible to send a custom UIView (no photos / video etc) to an apple tv through airplay as a second screen from an iPod touch 4th gen running ios 5.0.
Is it possible? Do I need iPad 2+ for this purpose?

Thanks in advance

Vassilis

p.s: I have read similar questions like: [Can I enable my App for AirPlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913408/can-i-enable-my-app-for-airplay) but the tools then were in early versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If airplay mirroring doesn't fit your needs, then take a look at the doco [Enriching your app for airplay](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html). In particular how you can gain separate access to both screens. You will have 2 uiwindows which can perform completely separate activities.